# php mysql left join count column same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can I do a left join the table Aste that all accounts concorso_id equal to id of the table concorsi ?

Table concorsi

```
id  name
1   car     
2   bike
3   boat
```

Table Aste

```
id  concorso_id
 1   1    
 2   1
 3   2
 4   2
 5   1
 6   3
```

I would like this result

```
id   name    count
1    car     3
2    bike    2
3    boat    1
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple join with group by should work:

```
select c.id, c.name, count(a.*) total
from concorsi c
    left join aste a on c.id = a.concorso_id
group by c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  concorsi.id,
  concorsi.name,
  COUNT(Aste.id) AS count
FROM
  concorsi
  LEFT JOIN Aste ON
    concorsi.id=Aste.concorsi_id
GROUP BY
  concorsi.id
```

For more references on how JOINS work please refer to the article [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) and always remember to refer back to the [MySQL man](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: I think your `count` should reference the `aste` table.

Comment: @user2480596 your right... sorry, I was going too fast.

Answer (score -1):

```
select c.id, c.name, count(concorso_id) 
from table concorsi as c, Aste as a 
where c.id=a.concorso_id group by concorso_id;
```

Comment: Please explain how this fixes the problem.

Comment: @DesertIvy Which problem? The OP is just asking for code.